# How do I fix this this loop for a simple username and password verification?

Tags: python

```
name = input('Enter your name')
password = 'Pas$Word'
while password:
    password = input('Enter your password')
if password:
    print("Welcome back John")
else:
    print("Incorrect password, try again...")
```

I'm brand new to coding and am trying to run a simple username and password verification using a while loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "fix this loop"?  It would help if you told us what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

you're taking input in the variable in which you stored the password initially

made these changes to your code

```
name = input('Enter your name')
check_password = 'Pas$Word'
while check_password:
    password = input('Enter your password')
    if password == check_password:
        print("Welcome back John")
    else: 
        print("Incorrect password, try again...")
```

Comment: or:
`print("Welcome back", name)`

Comment: ya, I just made necessary changes.